# How to retrieve image from MySQL database to PictureBox in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i'm trying to fetch an image into another form, all the text records from database are working fine, but when i add an image it has an error that says `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.Drawing.Image'.`, what am i missing out?

this is the code of my 1st form:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form5

Dim a As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
Public dc As Integer
Public ccfname As String
Public ccmname As String
Public cclname As String
Public ccpos As String
Public ccparty As String
Public photo As Image

Dim con As New MySqlConnection

Private Sub Form5_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=db;password=root"
        con.Open()
    End If
    LoadPeople()
End Sub

Public Sub LoadPeople()
    Dim sConnection As New MySqlConnection
    sConnection.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=db;password=root"
    sConnection.Open()
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE cfname<>'Select a Candidate' AND candidacy='Filed'"
    Dim sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim TABLE As New DataTable
    Dim i As Integer


    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .Connection = sConnection
    End With

    With sqlAdapter
        .SelectCommand = sqlCommand
        .Fill(TABLE)
    End With

    LvPeople.Items.Clear()

    For i = 0 To TABLE.Rows.Count - 1
        With LvPeople
            .Items.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("idn"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(AddFieldValue(TABLE.Rows(i), ("cpos")))
                .Add(AddFieldValue(TABLE.Rows(i), ("cfname")))
                .Add(AddFieldValue(TABLE.Rows(i), ("cmname")))
                .Add(AddFieldValue(TABLE.Rows(i), ("clname")))
                .Add(AddFieldValue(TABLE.Rows(i), ("cparty")))
            End With
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Private Function AddFieldValue(ByVal row As DataRow, ByVal fieldName As String) As String
    If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(row.Item(fieldName)) Then
        Return CStr(row.Item(fieldName))
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function

Private Sub lvPeople_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles LvPeople.MouseClick
    dc = LvPeople.SelectedItems(0).Text
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    If dc = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Please choose a record to view.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    Else

        Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
        con.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; user id = root; database = db; password = root"
        sqlCommand.Connection = con
        con.Open()
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE idn = '" & LvPeople.SelectedItems(0).Text & "'"
        Dim sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim sqlTabble As New DataTable

        With sqlCommand
            .CommandText = sqlQuery
            .Connection = con
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With

        With sqlAdapter
            .SelectCommand = sqlCommand
            .Fill(sqlTabble)
        End With
        Form25.dc = LvPeople.SelectedItems(0).Text
        Form25.ccfname = sqlTabble.Rows(0)("cfname")
        Form25.ccmname = sqlTabble.Rows(0)("cmname")
        Form25.cclname = sqlTabble.Rows(0)("clname")
        Form25.ccpos = sqlTabble.Rows(0)("cpos")
        Form25.ccparty = sqlTabble.Rows(0)("cparty")
        Form25.photo = sqlTabble.Rows(0)("photo")
        Form25.ShowDialog()
        con.Close()

        dc = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LvPeople_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LvPeople.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim connstring As String = "server = localhost; user id = root; database = db; password = root"
    Dim Sql As String = "SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE idn='" & LvPeople.SelectedItems(0).Text & "'"
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Sql, conn)
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
    conn.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dr.Read()
    Dim imagebytes As Byte() = CType(dr("photo"), Byte())
    Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(imagebytes)
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    End Using
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

and this is my 2nd form which i was trying to fetch the image to.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form25

Dim a As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
Public sConnection As New MySqlConnection
Friend dc As Integer
Friend ccfname As String
Friend ccmname As String
Friend cclname As String
Friend ccpos As String
Friend ccparty As String
Friend photo As Image

Private Sub Form25_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If sConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sConnection.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=db;password=root"
        sConnection.Open()
    End If
    Dim connstring As String = "server = localhost; user id = root; database = db; password = root"
    Dim Sql As String = "SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE idn='" & Form5.LvPeople.SelectedItems(0).Text & "'"
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connstring)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Sql, conn)
    TextBox2.Text = ccfname
    TextBox3.Text = ccmname
    TextBox4.Text = cclname
    ComboBox1.Text = ccpos
    TextBox1.Text = ccparty
    PictureBox1.Image = photo
End Sub
End Class
```

the error points here:

```
Form25.dc = LvPeople.SelectedItems(0).Text
        Form25.ccfname = sqlTabble.Rows(0)("cfname")
        Form25.ccmname = sqlTabble.Rows(0)("cmname")
        Form25.cclname = sqlTabble.Rows(0)("clname")
        Form25.ccpos = sqlTabble.Rows(0)("cpos")
        Form25.ccparty = sqlTabble.Rows(0)("cparty")
        Form25.photo = sqlTabble.Rows(0)("photo") <<--------------HERE------|
        Form25.ShowDialog()
        con.Close()
```

this is from the first form.

Comment: you have to do the same thing you do in `LvPeople_SelectedIndexChanged` and convert the byte array to an image using a memory stream.  `Form25.photo` is definded as an image, so you cant shove a byte array into it.  You should also turn on Option Strict and instance your forms - it appears there will be more problems in your near future

Comment: yeah, i already did that, i actually copied that and edited some lines, but still not working, what could i be missing?

Comment: what does "not working" mean?  you cant still be getting the same error in the same spot, are you?

Comment: but i'm still having the same error appearing at the same spot.

Comment: edit your post to show the actual code in its current form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use to do something similar.
This would let you use:

```
Form25.photo = Byte2Image(sqlTabble.Rows(0)("photo"))
```

You may need to do some explicit casting.

```
Public Shared Function Byte2Image(ByVal byteArr() As Byte) As Drawing.Image

    Using ImageStream As New MemoryStream(byteArr)
        Dim newImage As Drawing.Image
        Try
            If byteArr.GetUpperBound(0) > 0 Then
                newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ImageStream)
            Else
                newImage = Nothing
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            newImage = Nothing
        End Try
        Return newImage
    End Using

End Function
```